# Count Based on Age SQL

Tags: sql, count

I have the following T-SQL to calculate ages:

```
SELECT
  Member_ID,
  DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()) - 
  CASE 
    WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()),DOB) > GETDATE() THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS Age in Years
FROM MEMBER
WHERE YEAR(registration_date ) >= 2012
```

How do I count the number of member IDs for each age in years?

Comment: Have you tried using count? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: What do I put in it? Thanks.

Comment: @Bennef [Please don't use w3schools as a reference.](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: Aha, I see. I was unaware of the poor quality docs but have perused their site briefly for checking SQL. I will try to avoid in future.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using a subquery or CTE.  Much easier to follow:

```
SELECT AgeInYears, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT Member_ID,
             (DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()) - 
              CASE WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()),DOB) > GETDATE() THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS AgeinYears
      FROM MEMBER
      WHERE YEAR(registration_date ) >= 2012
     ) m
GROUP BY AgeInYears
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: One more question: how do I select only the three oldest members? Thanks.

Comment: That is a very different question.  You would add a `top 3` and `order by AgeInYears desc` to your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
-- Member_ID,  commented out
DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()) - 
CASE 
WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()),DOB) > GETDATE() THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS Age in Years
, count(member_id) membersWithThisAge
FROM MEMBER
WHERE YEAR(registration_date ) >= 2012
group by DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()) - 
CASE 
WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,GETDATE()),DOB) > GETDATE() THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

The member_id can't be included in the select clause.  If it were, then you would get a count of one age for each member.